# Reading SQLite DB table into Python

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am having trouble reading data into Python from a sqlite database located in the same directory as the Jupyter notebook where I am doing my work.

The error message (below) led me to believe that the table *Player_Attributes* does not exist in the database, but after exploring it with DB Browser for SQLite, I see that is is indeed there.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Code:

```
cnx = sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite')
df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM Player_Attributes', cnx)
```

Error message:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last) /home/captain/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)    1403             else:
-> 1404                 cur.execute(*args)    1405             return cur

OperationalError: no such table: Player_Attributes

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-4-c51fe6ea9537> in <module>()
      5 
      6 cnx = sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite')
----> 7 df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM Player_Attributes', cnx)

/home/captain/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in read_sql_query(sql, con, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, chunksize)
    330     return pandas_sql.read_query(
    331         sql, index_col=index_col, params=params, coerce_float=coerce_float,
--> 332         parse_dates=parse_dates, chunksize=chunksize)
    333 
    334 

/home/captain/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in read_query(self, sql, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, chunksize)    1437     1438         args = _convert_params(sql, params)
-> 1439         cursor = self.execute(*args)    1440         columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]    1441 

/home/captain/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)    1414             ex = DatabaseError(    1415                 "Execution failed on sql '%s': %s" % (args[0], exc))
-> 1416             raise_with_traceback(ex)    1417     1418     @staticmethod

/home/captain/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py in raise_with_traceback(exc, traceback)
    342         if traceback == Ellipsis:
    343             _, _, traceback = sys.exc_info()
--> 344         raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
    345 else:
    346     # this version of raise is a syntax error in Python 3

/home/captain/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)    1402                 cur.execute(*args, **kwargs)    1403             else:
-> 1404                 cur.execute(*args)    1405             return cur    1406         except Exception as exc:

DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM Player_Attributes': no such table: Player_Attributes
```

Comment: And what is the current directory while running this code?

Comment: The db and jupyter notebook are both at /Documents/data.science/micromasters/python4ds/Week5-Visualization/Week-5-Exercises-2

Comment: And what is the current directory (`os.getcwd()`)?

Comment: Okay it's working now and I feel really dumb. I think the error was originally thrown because I forgot to bring the db into the same directory, and it kept happening because I didn't clear the kernel after rectifying the oversight. Sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score 0):

```py
cnx = sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite')
```

In this line, instead of just specifying the name of the document, you have to provide the complete path of the file.